# Find all routes to template in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a large Symfony 4 project with many routes that sometimes render the same template. When modifying a template it would be helpful to know all the routes that use this template because sometimes a introduce a new variable that then has to be defined in all the controller functions that render this template. In the profiler I can see which templates are rendered for a route, but not the other way around. So my question is, is there any way to discover which controller actions / routes 'use' a certain template?

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15768 :(

Comment: @AhmedEBENHASSINE, thanks. A pity though....

Comment: How should this work? A controller can render multiple views (e.g. based on different params). Therefore this is some kind of feature which I guess will never be part of any web framework. You have to search all the references to the templates "by hand" (use your IDE ;) ).

Comment: While a rather large task, I suggest implementing Unit Testing into your project. This will allow you to test assertions for errors, such as undeclared variables required for your templates. When performing the unit test(s), it will show you an error of which objects failed the assertion(s) and should be updated. As an alternative, PHPStorm has a context menu option "Find Usage", which will find all the template file uses, in each of the controllers, manually rendered and within twig templates via include or extends.

Comment: How about a simple search in files project-wide?

Comment: @wp78de, a simple search does not work well. This is because I use includes of templates within other templates, which of course I can find, but I cannot connect a controller to it. I think unit testing is the way to go.